# How to draw a gradient with opacity

Tags: java, gradient, opacity, linear-gradients

I have this method, which makes a gradient, but for some reason I can not get it to make the gradient have any opacity, such as `60% opaque`.

```
public static int[] linear(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color1, Color color2, int width, int height){
    BufferedImage bimg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    Graphics2D g = bimg.createGraphics();
    g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(x1, y1, color1, x2, y2, color2, false));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    bimg.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
    return pixels;

}
```

I then call it like this:

```
int pink = Colors.rgba(187, 61, 186, 153);
int yellow = Colors.rgba(209, 192, 8, 153);
this.spixels = Gradient.linear(0, 0, img.getWidth(), 0, pink, yellow, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
```

I can not for the life of me get the gradient to be `60% opaque`. What can I do to make it like that?

**Here is some more background:**

I have an image, I then create a gradient the size of that image (with the above code). Next I blend the two images together using `lighten`:

```
public static int lighten(int bg, int fg){
    Color bgc = new Color(bg);
    Color fgc = new Color(fg);
    int r = Math.max(bgc.getRed(), fgc.getRed());
    int g = Math.max(bgc.getGreen(), fgc.getGreen());
    int b = Math.max(bgc.getBlue(), fgc.getBlue());
    int a = Math.max(bgc.getTransparency(), fgc.getTransparency());
    Color f = new Color(r, g, b, a);
    return f.getRGB();
}
```

No matter how transparent I make the gradient, lighten doesn't seem to catch it, and blends it with the full color, and ignores the transparency of the gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definen a `Composite` object like this

```
private static Composite comp = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f);
```

In `linear()` method, just set the composite before `g.fillRect()`

The following code snippet, demonstrates some thing like this in painting method of one of my codes...

```
        gg.setComposite(comp);
        Color ec = gg.getColor();

        gg.setColor(Color.darkGray);

        Shape s = gg.getClip();
        if (s != null)
            gg.fill(s);

        gg.setComposite(existing);
        gg.setColor(ec);
```